# Python ModuleNotFoundError for Custom Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, modulenotfounderror

I am importing a custom module called as Helper to my unittest. When I run with the help of test explorer it works fine, but when I try to run through command line it give me below error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Helper'
I have manually added empty **init**.py file at each directory and at project level as well.
My python version is : 3.8.3
Below is the error I get in CMD.
[error while running through command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itvvp.png)
Here is my folder structure ,result and code when I execute through test explorer.
[sampleTest.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt4nJ.png)

globalHelper.py
[globalHelper.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDjXu.png)

Comment: some code may be helpful

Comment: Are you able to see the code now?

Comment: can you show sampleTest? also there is no need for empty `__init__.py` files. But from what I see you have to import like this `from Helper.globalHelper import ReturnSomething`

Comment: I have added sampleTest.py as well. The code is of 12 lines only.

Answer (score 0):

first of no need for empty `__init__.py` files in those other directories. Now to import a module that is in a directory use:

```
from dir_name.module_name import what_you_need
```

hope I did not mess up some terms and that you understood what I meant

Comment: I am still getting the same error on doing this.
from Helper.globalHelper import ReturnSomething
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Helper'

Comment: as I said script to whom you import has to be in the same directory as the `Helper` directory and then there has to be that `__init__` directory as well so the three things: `main file`, `module directory` and `default directories that are already created` have to be in the same directory

Comment: Thanks You Matiiss.Importing to same directory works! But is there any reason why it does not work from command line when its in different directory? It works fine when I execute it from test explorer when using two directories. As I am trying to make a framework I would like to have proper directories for test data, utilities, test cases, etc. Thanks again.

Comment: maybe because it cannot reach that file because it possibly is looking for built in directories and cannot find them